# print(__doc__) in Python 3 script

Tags: python, docstring

I can't figure out what does the `print(__doc__)` do at the beginning of a script, like [in this Scikit example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#example-classification-plot-digits-classification-py).

I have been looking for **Python docstrings** in google, and it seems `__doc__` is useful to provide some documentation in, say, functions. But I can't see what does `__doc__` do in the middle of a script.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> it seems `__doc__` is useful to provide some documentation in, say, functions

This is true. In addition to functions, documentation can also be provided in modules. So, if you have a file named `mymodule.py` like this:

```
"""This is the module docstring."""

def f(x):
    """This is the function docstring."""
    return 2 * x
```

You can access its docstrings like this:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.__doc__
'This is the module docstring.'
>>> mymodule.f.__doc__
'This is the function docstring.'
```

Now, back to your question: what does `print(__doc__)` do? Simply put: it prints the module docstring. If no docstring has been specified, `__doc__` defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 24):

Any function, class *or module* starting with a string literal has a non-empty `__doc__`; that initial string is taken as the documentation string; it'll be set to `None` if no such string is present. See the [*docstring* term definition](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring) in the Python glossary.

When you download that Scikit script example, you'll see it starts with such a string:

```
"""
================================
Recognizing hand-written digits
================================

An example showing how the scikit-learn can be used to recognize images of
hand-written digits.

This example is commented in the
:ref:`tutorial section of the user manual <introduction>`.

"""
```

The `print(__doc__)` command simply re-uses that documentation string to write it to your terminal each time you run the script, and any other python tool (like the interactive interpreter `help()` function, for example) can introspect that same value.