# I can print object.__doc__ but I can't save it to a file

Tags: python, object, doc

As mentioned in the subject line for a given objec (module or class)

```
print (object.__doc__)   works
document.write (object.__doc__)
TypeError" write: () argument must be a str not None
```

I do get `type(object.__doc__)` is None

**Update:**
Grrr...indeed the first object in the list had not doc string
Now the error mutated to 
TypeError" must be a str not type

Comment: Cannot reproduce: on my machine, `type(object.__doc__)` gives `<type 'str'>`. Do you have a complete example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does `print(object.__doc__)` print? `None`?

Comment: I think this can answer part of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066383/print-doc-in-python-3-script no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by `object` you don't mean the built-in `object` class but rather your own class.

For `__doc__` to not be `None`, the class in question has to have a docstring.

Contrast:

```
>>> class X(object):
...    pass
... 
>>> type(X.__doc__)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

with:

```
>>> class Y(object):
...    "Class Y"
... 
>>> type(Y.__doc__)
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Yes that was the case..the problem is that I was looking at the next object that did have the __doc__ string
Now I am facing another issue ..please see the update