# Putting a string below a function definition in Python

Tags: python, django

I was reading the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods), and I came across this code:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"
```

What is the purpose of putting a string below a function definition i.e `baby_boomer_status()`?

Comment: It works as a code comment. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33066383/4180176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called the [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Is not only for code commenting, but also can be accessed from the `.__doc__` method to check info about the funcion:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but the examples you provided in your answer used explicit comments. On the other hand, the example I gave uses a string. Is there a difference?